# Переключение между меню JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет!

Мне необходимо, чтобы когда я кликаю на `menu-item-has-children` к классу `sub-menu` добавлялся класс `show-submenu`.

Мой код при клике на `menu-item-has-children` добавляет ко всем `sub-menu` класс, а мне нужно что бы он добавлялся только к тому на который я кликнул + что бы он убирался когда я кликаю по другому `menu-item-has-children`

Тут я написал часть кода.

```js
$('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').not(this).removeClass("show-submenu");
    $('.sub-menu').toggleClass("show-submenu");
  });
```

```css
.menu-item-has-children {cursor: pointer;}
.sub-menu {display: none;}
.show-submenu {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-item-has-children">
  Мое меню
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="menu-item-has-children">
  Мое меню
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Помогите пожалуйста улучшить код, что бы он добавлял класс только к тому элементу на который я кликаю.

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй `.children()`

```js
$('.menu-item-has-children').click(function() {
    $('.menu-item-has-children').not(this).removeClass("show-submenu");
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').toggleClass("show-submenu");
  });
```

```css
.menu-item-has-children {cursor: pointer;}
.sub-menu {display: none;}
.show-submenu {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu-item-has-children">
  Мое меню
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="menu-item-has-children">
  Мое меню
  <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>1</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто! Работает 
Я добавил .children `.not(this).children('.sub-menu').removeClass("show-submenu");`
Что бы удалять класс при клике на другой элемент. Это верное решение?